# Best practice for tracking the user's "current object" on a website

Tags: java, web

When a user is interacting with a website, there's usually some object that could be considered the "current" object, like a shopping cart, or, to use an example in my world, a manufacturing job. What's the best practice for tracking that current object from page to page? I can think of a few:

1. put the ID as a request parameter (downside is security, since a
   hacker could use that to change the URL to a different ID)
2. a session object (downside is if you have a huge amount of users
   and/or the current object has a large memory footprint)
3. cookie? (Haven't tried that one)

Have I missed some obvious answer?

BTW, we're using Java, WebLogic and Struts1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your technology stack as to what "best practice" would be for you right now.

For example, if you're building a traditional Rails application using ERB templates without a MVC front end or anything, then I think that using the session object that the Rails framework provides for you would be best.

Most web frameworks will supply you an easy way to keep track of a particular user that's browsing the website. Most of the ones I've seen use a combination of your second and third options. They have a session ID that is stored as a cookie in the user's browser and every time that user sends a request to the web server, it loads a Session object from memory or the database using the session ID value that was stored in that cookie. Memory shouldn't be an issue unless you have an enormous number of users, but that also depends on the type of information that you're storing in there.

If you're storing entire database rows or records, and the sessions are being stored totally in memory, then maybe you should consider only storing the IDs to those records.

Research your particular web framework well to see how it handles user sessions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with how the session ID is stored as a cookie. I was more wondering if storing the current object itself in a cookie would be a best practice or not.

Comment: I would recommend against it. I tried it once, but then I ran into issues once the data that was being stored into the session became stale, invalid or out of sync with what was actually in the database.

Answer (score 2):

As far as a cross-platform best practice, the Session object paradigm seems tot be the best approach to date.  It permits matching of request parameters to tracking of sessions independent of the handling of the request parameter.  An extension to this is that the Session object provides a handy place to put a collection of things for use if the session is re-identified (Java uses a Map).

Generally the Session is a representation of a single web browser visiting a single website repeatedly.  Since there is nothing associating one request to another, this is generated synthetically from a combination of items, including user agent string, reply ip address, etc (in the past it was a stored value in a cookie, which caused no end to security issues).

Assuming you have a reliable Session object available, typically one stores the items that a supposed "single user" driving the session should have access to.  So, if you have a shopping cart, it might be represented as a shopping cart object accessible from the session.  In Java, that might be a map.

When identifying a new session

```
// request is a HttpServletRequest object in this example
if (request.getSession(false)) {
  // must be a new one
  Session newSession = request.getSession(true);
  newSession.putValue("shoppingCart", new ShoppingCart());
}
```

Later on, when adding to the cart

```
ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)(request.getSession(false).getValue("shoppingCart"));
cart.addItem(item);
```

The benefits of separating out the detection from the request handling make it easy to fix / tweak session tracking without altering the code for the "session contents".

Answer (score 1):

The other Answers are correct. Just a bit more explanation.

The Java [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) technology’s [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) object is indeed aimed at solving this exact problem, how to track a single user’s set of current objects over time, beyond the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request-response lifecycle. This lends statefulness to an otherwise stateless protocol (HTTP). Every Servlet container ([Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org), Jetty, WildFly, and so on) automatically handles the details such as using [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) or [URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting) so you needn't worry about that.

Yes, as you add stuff to the Session object its memory usage grows in size. If running low on memory, your Servlet container such as Tomcat may choose to write an older Session object to storage using [Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html). The catch here is that all your objects in the Session must be serializable. Ensuring your classes (and all their nested objects) can correctly handle serialization can be a big chore.

Tip: If possible add memory to your server to more that handle your highest session load. As the wise man said, "Algorithms are for people who don’t know how to buy [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).".